# How to upload a complete directory hierarchy structure to artifactory using Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

How to upload a complete directory hierarchy structure to artifactory using Jenkins? 
I have a workspace folder with all the artifacts, organized in subdirectories.
How can I keep the hierarchy structure in the artifactory?

Answer (score 4):

You should use the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin together with a file spec to define the Artifacts that need to be uploaded. In the file spec docs https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+File+Specs#UsingFileSpecs-UploadSpecSchema pay attention to the "flat" and "recursive" options as you probably want to set flat to false.